# Is GtkIconView height incorrect if height of rows are not equal?

Tags: python, c++, c, gtk3

Suppose we try to change the height of a GtkIconView showing a column with rows different in their height. How can we achieve this or is this impossible?

If you have rows with equal height the height of the IconView is correct.

[image]

But if not, it is not.

[image]

Adjusting the adjustment of the Scrollable of the IconView is possible but have no effect on the height. The same is true if we change the adjustment of the ScrolledWindow wherein the IconView is normally placed. Nor does have '''gtk_widget_set_size_request''' any effect. This is at least true for GTK3.18.9 version.

How can we set the correct height for the IconView?

Comment: One question: are you changing the `IconView` _while_ the code is running, or do you just start out with the smaller items? It would help, even it it's not necessary, if you provided a [example]...

Comment: MRE: You are right. I do not, because an example uses one binding and someone who can help but does not know this may not answer. This is a simple IconView with a pixbuf column sitting in a ScrolledWindow. The pixbufs have height 8 or 24 pixels. Nothing special I guess.

Comment: I tried to change the size request as the adjustment changes while running. But the "wrong" IconView height occurs just after starting with the mixed heights of the pixbuf rows.